# bind9 with $GENERATE in PTR records and a lots of 'ignoring out-of-zone data'

Tags: bind

I have a next issue. I have subnet 92.222.0.0/17 and I rule reverse records of it. Definitions of zones are the next:

```
    zone "123.222.92.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "rev/db.92.222.0-127";
};

zone "124.222.92.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "rev/db.92.222.0-127";
};
```

In this single file I have a lot of:

```
$ORIGIN 0.222.92.in-addr.arpa.
...
$ORIGIN 123.222.92.in-addr.arpa.
$ORIGIN 124.222.92.in-addr.arpa.
```

In them I put a lot

```
$ORIGIN 123.222.92.in-addr.arpa.
$GENERATE 1-254        $ PTR   fr2-a$.example.net. 
$ORIGIN 124.222.92.in-addr.arpa.
$GENERATE 10-139        $ PTR   fr2-b$.example.net.
```

All is wokring fine exept starting of bind and checking file zones with named-checkzone. In log file I have

```
named[4256]: rev/db.92.222.0-127:83: ignoring out-of-zone data (47.1.222.92.in-addr.arpa)
```

So for every string which contains $GENERATE bind is generating this warning. Try to find, how it possible to fix and no success. bind is starting at least for 40 seconds till 2 minutes differ of server.
Probably somebody can help me here?
Thank you!

Comment: Probably will answer for question for long start, just in logging section changed category default into null. Startup from 42 seconds decrease to 2 seconds.

Comment: I suppose that works around the problem with the startup time caused by your many thousands of warnings, but the problem with your setup that causes the warnings is still there, you just turned off logging (which may very well get rid of other log entries that you may care more about as well).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not specific to reverse zones or `$GENERATE`, rather general for any case where there is data that belongs to some different zone in the zone file specified for a given zone.

Simply have one zone file per zone and this should not be an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure about creating 128 separate files for each zone. Also, config check doesn't says something wrong about regular record: `$ORIGIN 0.222.92.in-addr.arpa. 1       IN      PTR     fr-edge-hsrp-be20-2001.example.net.` So issue about ignoring out of zone  appears only for strings in file with $GENERATE

Comment: @AntonSamets You rather mean something like "128 separate files, one for each zone", right? Also, you do get the exact same problem with completely static records. https://gist.github.com/hlindqvist/1014c922624db96e0d71